# PostgreSQL procedure return different result based on if statement

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  FUNCTION QPS_PROC_REPORT_ON_WAYBILL (strfrmdatde  text,WaybillNo  text,strreportfo text,WaybillNo1  text,strreportfo1  text,condition1  text,DUMMY  text,DUMMY1  text) RETURNS SETOF refcursor


    AS $$
    Declare swv_refcur refcursor;
    swv_refcur2 refcursor;
    DECLARE r record;
    Declare 
    date2 text;
    date3 text;
    TABLE_NAME2 text;
    TABLE_NAME3 text;

    BEGIN 
      if strfrmdatde is  NOT null
      and strreportfo is  nulL
      and WaybillNo1 is  null
      and strreportfo1 is  nulL
      and DUMMY is  nulL
      and DUMMY1 is  nulL then

      open SWV_RefCur for SELECT 
      DISTINCT(EID_WAYBILL_NO) 
      FROM ETM_ISSUE_DETAILS 
      WHERE  EID_DT_CID = strfrmdatde 
      ORDER BY EID_WAYBILL_NO;
      return next SWV_RefCur;
      end if;

      if  WaybillNo is NOT null
      and strreportfo is NOT null
      THEN

       select substring(strfrmdatde,1,6) into date2;  
       TABLE_NAME2:=(select concat('ETM_TICKET_DATA',date2));


      open SWV_RefCur for SELECT 
       ETD_TICKET_NAME,COUNT(ETD_ADULTS),SUM(ETD_AMOUNT) 
       FROM TABLE_NAME2 WHERE ETD_WAYBILL_NO = WaybillNo 
       AND ETD_TICKET_TYPE1 = strreportfo   
       group by ETD_TICKET_NAME;
       return next SWV_RefCur;

       END IF;


        if  WaybillNo is  null
        and strreportfo is  nulL
        and WaybillNo1 is NOT null
        and strreportfo1 is NOT nulL

         THEN
         select substring(strfrmdatde,1,6) into date3;  
         TABLE_NAME3:=(select concat('ETM_TICKET_DATA',date3));


           open SWV_RefCur for SELECT
           ETD_TICKET_NAME,COUNT(ETD_ADULTS),SUM(ETD_AMOUNT)
           FROM TABLE_NAME3 WHERE ETD_WAYBILL_NO= WaybillNo1  
           AND ETD_TICKET_TYPE1= strreportfo1   
           condition1 GROUP BY ETD_TICKET_NAME;
           return next SWV_RefCur;

           END IF;
     END;
     $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I need to get the resulted records with different number of columns based on condition

Comment: First: a procedure is not the right way to return results, that's what functions are for. Secondly: you can't really have dynamic columns. Postgres needs to know the number of result columns before the statement is run.

Comment: Unrelated, but: don't use `SELECT` for simple assignments. e.g. `TABLE_NAME2:=(select concat('ETM_TICKET_DATA',date2));` can be simplified to `TABLE_NAME2 := concat('ETM_TICKET_DATA',date2);`